# Bug in the calculation of upvotes for specific tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tagging, voting

I've stumbled across what seems to be a (small) bug regarding the calculation of upvotes for specific tags. Sometimes (probably because of tag merging), a question will exhibit the same tag *twice* -- e.g., [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand) is tagged with [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros) [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros) (one of these very likely was a [newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newcommand) before). Upvotes for answers to these questions will correctly be counted only once for the calculation of the "top users" (and potential tag badge earners) of this tag, but they will be counted twice in the tag upvote statistic of one's user profile. For example, compare the number of upvotes for [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros)  [top user](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/macros/topusers) Joseph Wright (186) with the [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros) upvotes on his [user profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) (214).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, good point. I removed all the duplicate tags across the SE 2.0 network just now.

We should probably change tag renaming and merging so it doesn't create duplicate tags on posts.

Comment: @Jeff: There are still some duplicates, e.g. [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/tableofcontents-and-listoffigures-help).

Comment: @lock that's really odd, ah wait I know.. if a tag exists in triplicate (or quadruplicate) on a question, it takes multiple runs.

Comment: Jeff: *it takes multiple runs* - It's like Bibtex, then.

Comment: Not sure if it is direct related but in my profile on the [candidate statistic page](http://se.awio.com/election.html) there is the `beamer` tag listed twice.

Comment: @Jeff: after a merge we've got [some questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10435/underfull-hbox-error-on-tabular-context) with double {table} tag. Could you please run tag deduplication again? Thanks!

Comment: @stefan done, quite a lot of duplicates

Comment: @stefan @jeff The dupes are fixed in a scheduled task, I just fixed the merge tag logic so it does not create dupes in the first place

Answer (score 3):

It's not perfectly clear to me that it is exactly the same problem, but from meta.SO, [Why are there questions with duplicate tags once in a while?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20929/why-are-there-questions-with-duplicate-tags-once-in-a-while), Jeff answers:

> So the next time there's a duplicate tag problem, just flag one of them for moderator attention and we'll run the tag deduplicator page.

So if any moderators should happen to read this, ones who happen to know what the tag deduplicator page is, maybe they will know if it is the tool for the job or not.

Comment: @Charles: Thanks for the link -- it seems that the calculation bug is a follow-up problem of duplicate tags, and that it can be resolved by using this "deduplicator".

Comment: BTW, I'm out of votes for today (I spent some time reading old meta-questions).

Comment: I flagged the "example question" for moderator attention.

Comment: Well, I can't find it!

Comment: @lockstep: I'm trying to find out where this function is. I'll report back if/when I do.

Comment: I didn't find it yet as well.

Comment: @Joseph,Stefan: I'm guessing it is a developer tool and not a moderator tool.

Comment: @Charles: From what Jeff says, I guess it was available for the SO site itself, and not the newer ones. Hopefully the situation can be dealt with properly by altering the back-end to prevent duplicate tags in the first place.